# Mongoose - Can not create db after Node.js server restart

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am maintaining a Node.js-MongoDb application. I am not the author of code and now trying to understand it. My problem is like that ,

My code uses Mongoose for db operations. There is a **model** folder in application path. In this folder there are all needed object files.For example feedback.js,user.js etc. Example content of Feedback.js is like;

```
var Repository = require('./base/Repository');
var Connection = require('./base/Connection');

var scm = Repository.schema({
    userId : String,
    text: String,
    date: Number
});

scm.index({date:1});
scm.index({userId:1});

var repo = Repository.create('Feedback', scm, Connection);

module.exports = new repo();
```

Example content of the Connection.js file under the base folder

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017/MyDb');

var getDb = function () {
    return db;
};

module.exports = {
    'getDb' : getDb
};
```

Now when I start node application, it automatically create databases if they do not exists.There is no problem until here.

The problem starts when I try to create a new database.I tried to create a new database. So I created a Connection file like the given example. Then I created an object file under the model folder like in the example. But when I restart my node application (pm2 restart ....) my database is not created.

Is there a file that says Mongoose "Create this databaes." I could not file any configuration file in the application folder. What is my problem ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Requiring the created model somewhere in the code solved my problem.

```
var xxx=require(model/mymodel)
```

I think Mongoose is creating the only required models